# spfx MSGraphClientt

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

I need to write a webpart, which shows data from the MS Graph.

I wrote this example code

```
     import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
    import {
      BaseClientSideWebPart,
      IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
      PropertyPaneTextField
    } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
    import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

    import styles from './HelloWorldWebPart.module.scss';
    import * as strings from 'HelloWorldWebPartStrings';
    //import { MSGraphClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

    import { MSGraphClient } from "@microsoft/sp-client-preview";


    import { default as pnp, ItemAddResult } from "sp-pnp-js";

    export interface IHelloWorldWebPartProps {

      mail: string;

    }

export default class HelloWorldWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWorldWebPartProps> {
  public async render() {


    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <div class="${ styles.helloworld}">
        <div class="${ styles.container}">
          <div class="${ styles.row}">
            <div class="${ styles.column}">
              <span class="${ styles.title}">HelloWorld</span>

              <p class="${ styles.description}">Mail: ${escape(this.properties.mail)}</p>

              <a href="#" class="${ styles.button}" id="submit">
                <span class="${ styles.label}">Submit</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`;


  }

protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [

                PropertyPaneTextField('mail', {
                  label: 'Mail'
                  value: result.mail
                }),

              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  protected async onInit(): Promise<void> {
    await super.onInit();
    // your code to get your data and affect it to a property of the class

    //get data with graph

    const client: MSGraphClient = this.context.serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClient.serviceKey);
    client
      .api("me/")
      .get()
      .then((res: any): void => {
        console.log(res);
        result = res;

      });

  }
}
```

How can I get the data with graph, before the webpart render?
I tried with onInit, but i get the data after the webart render.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please check out this video, it might be helpful for you - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BOWmMq1NTw

Answer (score 0):

You need to return promise after the call has completed, as you can see the promise returns void for the onInit method which you can change to your required model or any and resolve it once you have fetched the data.